# SELECT SQL Matching Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I have millions of rows of data that have similar values ​​like this:

```
Id    Reff    Amount
1     a1       1000
2     a2      -1000
3     a3      -2500
4     a4      -1500
5     a5       1500
```

every data must have positive and negative values. the question is, how do I show only records that don't have a similar value? like a row Id 3. thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.amount = -1 * t.amount)
```

A `left join` antipattern would also get the job done:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.amount = -1 * t.amount
where t1.id is null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4c42b367fc9d7325fd3cb4996fff1502)**:

```
Id | Reff | Amount
-: | :--- | -----:
 3 | a3   |  -2500
```

Comment: one point to note on this solution is that it will only find records that don't have their anti-value. so a6 = -2500 would show up twice. This may or may not be desired behaviour

Comment: @el_oso: *every data must have positive and negative values* : yes, I think that this is exactly what OP wants...

Comment: I agree, which is why I've voted this as the correct answer. I'm simply pointing out a potential gotcha when you can have the same value appearing more than once.

Comment: el_oso - I see what you mean there.  Also, any number of -2500 records would be unselected by any single +2500 record existing - if you wanted one-to-one matches, you'd need to add row_numbers for similar values, and join on them also.  I'm not saying any of this solution is wrong though, it does do what is asked for.  there is also a question mark over a single zero(which is not positive or negative of course)

Comment: I have tried this method, but the issue is processing time. I have 65 million rows of data, it really takes a long time to run the query.

Comment: @DedeMuhamadYusup: for performance, you need an index on amount. Do you have this index already?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f24e28/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
   Id     int  
  ,Reff   varchar(2)
  ,Amount int  
);
INSERT INTO Test(Id,Reff,Amount) VALUES (1,'a1',1000);
INSERT INTO Test(Id,Reff,Amount) VALUES (2,'a2',-1000);
INSERT INTO Test(Id,Reff,Amount) VALUES (3,'a3',-2500);
INSERT INTO Test(Id,Reff,Amount) VALUES (4,'a4',-1500);
INSERT INTO Test(Id,Reff,Amount) VALUES (5,'a5',1500);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
from Test t
left join Test t1 on t1.amount =ABS(t.amount)
where t1.id is null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f24e28/3/0)**:

```
| Id | Reff | Amount |
|----|------|--------|
|  3 |   a3 |  -2500 |
```

Comment: you'd get different answers for a3 = 2500 and a6 = 2500 and the situation where a3 = -2500 and a6 = -2500. For this approach you should ABS() both sides

Answer (score 0):

Using a `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN` will work fine to find the amounts that don't have an opposite amount in the data.

But to really find the amounts that don't balance out with an Amount sorted by ID?
For such SQL puzzle it should be handled as a Gaps-And-Islands problem.

So the solution might appear a bit more complicated, but it's actually quite simple.

It first calculates a ranking per absolute value.

And based on that ranking it filters the last amount where the SUM per ranking isn't balanced out (not 0)

```
SELECT Id, Reff, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
     SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk) AS SumAmountByRank,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk  ORDER BY Id DESC) AS Rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id, Reff, Amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) -  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(Amount) ORDER BY Id) AS Rnk
        FROM YourTable
    ) AS q1
) AS q2
WHERE SumAmountByRank != 0
  AND Rn = 1
ORDER BY Id;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/DQBF55618)

If the sequence doesn't matter, and just the balance matters?
Then the query can be simplified.

```
SELECT Id, Reff, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Reff, Amount,
     SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(Amount)) AS SumByAbsAmount,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ABS(Amount) ORDER BY Id DESC) AS Rn
    FROM YourTable
) AS q
WHERE SumByAbsAmount != 0
  AND Rn = 1
ORDER BY Id;
```